# I can't receive data from Arduino through Bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, android, java

I am developing an app that controls an Arduino robot. For that I need to communicate through Bluetooth. That means sending and receiving data. Why receiving? Because I also have sensors on the robot. I am already able to successfully connect with the Arduino Bluetooth bridge and send data, but I can't receive data from the Arduino. If someone can help me, I will appreciate it.

Here is the  main Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button  forward_btn, forward_left_btn, forward_right_btn, reverse_btn, reverse_right_btn, reverse_left_btn, btnConexao, turbo;
    public static final int SOLICITA_ATIVACAO = 1; // é o codigo numero 1, é diferenciado o codigo pq pode haver varias solicitações na msma tela
    public static final int SOLICITA_CONEXAO = 2;
    BluetoothAdapter meuBluetoothAdapter = null; //declarar o meu adptador bluetooth
    BluetoothDevice meuDevice = null;
    BluetoothSocket meuSocket = null; // faz transiçao dos dados
    TextView myLabel;
    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;
    boolean conexao =  false; //variavel para a conexao que indica se a conexao está em andamento ou nao
    private OutputStream outputStream  ;
    private static String MAC = null;
    private  InputStream mmInputStream;
    final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1; // Status  for Handler
    Handler h;
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte [] command = new byte[256]; //string variable that will store value to be transmitted to the bluetooth module
    UUID MEU_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // canal de comunicaçao bluetooth, UUID- ID do canal
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      forward_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_btn); //definir botoes e associar ao ficheiro xml
      forward_left_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_left_btn);
      forward_right_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_right_btn);
      reverse_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reverse_btn);
      reverse_left_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reverse_left_btn);
      reverse_right_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reverse_right_btn);
      btnConexao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConexao);
      turbo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turbo);
      myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
      forward_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { // comandos bluetooth correspondentes do arduino
          if (conexao) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              command = "1".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command); //transmite o valor do comando para o modulo bluetooth
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              command = "10".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

      reverse_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (conexao) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              command = "2".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              command = "10".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

      forward_left_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (conexao) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              command = "3".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              command = "10".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

      forward_right_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (conexao) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              command = "4".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              command = "10".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

      reverse_left_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (conexao) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              command = "5".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              command = "10".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

      reverse_right_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (conexao) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              command = "6".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              command = "10".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

      turbo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (conexao) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              command = "9".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              command = "10".getBytes();
              try {
                outputStream.write(command);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

      meuBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); //obter o adaptador do dispositivo e definir como meubluetoothADpt
      if (meuBluetoothAdapter == null) { //se o adptador for "null", ou seja nao tem adptador
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O seu dispositivo nao possui bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else if (!meuBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { // != não, so o bluetooth nao tiver ativao, pedir permissão
        Intent ativaBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(ativaBluetooth, SOLICITA_ATIVACAO);
      }

      btnConexao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if (conexao) {
            try {
              meuSocket.close();
              conexao = false;
              btnConexao.setText("Conectar");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth foi desconectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException erro) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro ao desconectar:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          } else {
            Intent abreLista = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListaDispositivos.class);
            startActivityForResult(abreLista, SOLICITA_CONEXAO);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    void beginListenForData () {
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character
      stopWorker = false;
      readBufferPosition = 0;
      readBuffer = new byte[1024];
      workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
            try {
              int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
              if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                  byte b = packetBytes[i];
                  if (b == delimiter) {
                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                    readBufferPosition = 0;
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                        myLabel.setText(data);
                      }
                    });
                  } else {
                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                  }
                }
              }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
              stopWorker = true;
            }
          }
        }
      });
      workerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      switch (requestCode) {
        case SOLICITA_ATIVACAO:
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O Bluetooth foi ativado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O bluetooth nao foi ativado, App será encerrada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
          }
          break;
        case SOLICITA_CONEXAO: // pede resultado da solicitaçao, se nao obter o resultado exibe toast
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            MAC = data.getExtras().getString(ListaDispositivos.ENDERECO_MAC);//vai buscar info à lista, ao ENDERECO_MAC
            meuDevice = meuBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC); // obtem dispositivo remoto atraves do MAC
            try { // tenta a conexao
              meuSocket = meuDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MEU_UUID); // cria um canal de comunicaça0 Rfcomm
              meuSocket.connect(); // tenta conexao  exibre
              try {
                outputStream = meuSocket.getOutputStream();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              try {
                mmInputStream = meuSocket.getInputStream();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                beginListenForData();
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              conexao = true; // apos conectado, passa a true
              btnConexao.setText("Desconectar");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Você foi conectado com" + MAC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException erro) { // se falhar conexao exibe
              conexao = false;
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro:" + erro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //retirar o "+erro" se for publicada a app
            }
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falha ao obter o mac", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
    }
}
```

This is the code I added in order to receive data:

```
  void beginListenForData () {
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character
  stopWorker = false;
  readBufferPosition = 0;
  readBuffer = new byte[1024];
  workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
        try {
          int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
          if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
              byte b = packetBytes[i];
              if (b == delimiter) {
                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                readBufferPosition = 0;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    myLabel.setText(data);
                  }
                });
              } else {
                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
              }
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          stopWorker = true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  workerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you receive data through bluetooth using a standard terminal emulator program?

Comment: I used the "Bluetooth terminal " to check if the arduino is sending data , and it is working well but i can't receive it in my app .

Comment: So it sounds like it's something Android specific then - you may be better off asking on an Android site where they have more Android knowledge.

Comment: You were right , the problem was it the arduino code , thank you for your time.